# comparing and replacing two pandas dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that has 2 columns, and all the values are string.

I want to compare the columns and replace the first column to the second column value if the second column string is longer than the first column.

For instance, if `df.iloc[0,0] = 'apple'` and `df.iloc[0,1] = 'banana'`, then `df.iloc[0,0]` would be replaced to '`banana`'

I will appreciate any advice. =]

Answer (score 4):

Compare by [`Series.str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html) and set values in [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) with [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for select by positions:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['apple','orange'], 'b':['banana','pear']})
print (df)
        a       b
0   apple  banana
1  orange    pear

mask = df.iloc[:,0].str.len() > df.iloc[:,1].str.len()
df.iloc[:,0] = np.where(mask, df.iloc[:,0], df.iloc[:,1])
#alternative
#df.iloc[~mask.to_numpy(),0] = df.iloc[:,1]
print (df)
        a       b
0  banana  banana
1  orange    pear
```

If is possible use labels of columns:

```
mask = df['a'].str.len() > df['b'].str.len()
df['a'] = np.where(mask, df['a'], df['b'])
#alternative
#df.loc[~mask, 'a'] = df['b']
```